# Is there a known reason why the Darksaber was kept in the Jedi Temple?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-clone-wars

The TV series [*Star Wars: The Clone Wars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Clone_Wars_(2008_TV_series)) introduced a new (but ancient) lightsaber known as [Darksaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber).

According to (canon) legend, this one of a kind lightsaber was allegedly created by and belonged to the the first ever Mandalorian to join the Jedi Order.

> **The Darksaber was an ancient and unique black-bladed lightsaber created by Tarre Vizsla, the first Mandalorian ever inducted into the Jedi Order, prior to 1019 BBY. The weapon was kept in the Jedi Temple after Vizsla's passing, but members of House Vizsla stole the saber in a conflict with the Jedi during the fall of the Old Republic**. The Darksaber was passed down, generation to generation, by the ancestors of Pre Vizsla, who held onto the weapon even after the pacifist ideals of the New Mandalorians replaced the warrior ways of Mandalore.

However, after Terre Vizsla's death,, the Darksaber was kept by the Jedi, until it was stolen by House Vizla.

I have not seen much of *The Clone Wars* TV series and the Wookieepedia entry does not seem to say much about this conflict between the Jedi and Mandalorians of this era, or how and/or why Vizla was killed, but I was wondering if there are ANY explanations given as to why the Jedi would have kept the weapon and/or have not just freely have given it to House Vizla?

---

To better understand the context of my question, the Darksaber shows up again not only in *Star Wars: Rebels* and *Darth Maul: Son of Dathomir*, but also

> *The Mandalorian*!

This prompts me to more deeply consider the weapon's abilities and if its kyber crystal could ever be aligned with the dark side of the Force, as

> *The Mandalorian* has potential to fill in *some of the sequel trilogy's backstory, most noticeably the resurrection of Darth Sidious and/or the return of the Sith.

Now perhaps it is a "neutral" kyber crystal and anyone can use it, but I just feel like there is a lot of missing information in its backstory that seems to feed into a conflict between the Jedi (who normally do not hold onto objects, as Jedi are often encouraged or expected to make their own lightsabers at some point. In fact it's more likley for a Sith to steal and corrupt another's object) and the Mandalorians/House Vizla (as lightsabers are NOT traditional Mandalorian weapons, even though Mandalorians have used the Darksaber to conquer Mandalore during the Clone Wars).

Everything in the Darksaber's backstory is dancing around the contention of a Mandalorian vs being a Jedi and what this Darksaber actually is/does, which goes hand-in-hand with other aspects of *The Mandalorian* 1.08...

> The Armorer tells Djarin that he must teach the Child and be his father, but eventually, he must also find the Child's creed in either it' species or the Jedi. The Child is then on a trajectory similar to Terre Vizla being caught between the creed of the Mandalorian and the Force (the Jedi/the Sith).

Comment: I would be surprised if the Darksaber were aligned with the dark side, because (a) it's established that using the dark side to corrupt a kyber crystal changes its color to red, not black, which is why every dark side user in canon has a red lightsaber if they have one at all (b) in Legends it was created by a Jedi, not a Sith, (c) it didn't seem to have any negative effect on non-dark-side Force users to be around it or maybe even use it.

Comment: It seems more probable that it is either (a) the effect of the unique personality of a Mandalorian Jedi, much as Mace Windu's purple color or the yellow color of Jedi temple guards indicated a certain state of mind, or (b) ancient Mandalorian technology used to create a lightsaber analogue without using the Force.

Comment: Maybe it's neutral (equal in the light and the dark), meaning you don't have to corrupt it to use it? But I feel like it was given this name intentionally and so far I have not found evidence explaining some of these missing pieces from it's backstory. I mean the Jedi also could of just destroyed it---unless it's been undestroyable (since when do they keep lightsabers and don't push for new force users making their own?)---but I think to bring into this story with this particular character, suggest something is going on here....

Comment: I mean were the Mandos mad at the Jedi simply for not giving the saber to them or is this conflict about the Mandos believing that Vizla was corrupted by the Jedi or the kyber crystal? Why did they want it, since it is not a traditional Mandalorian weapon? Why was there a conflict? What happened to Vizla? But it seems like it's all interrelated.

Comment: "I just feel like there is a lot of missing information in its backstory"... It seems that Disney has heard you. See [Why It’s Exciting That The Mandalorian Season 2 Will Explore the Darksaber](https://www.themarysue.com/mandalorian-season-2-darksaber/)

Comment: @agarza I saw that too! :)

Comment: @agarza well, that didnt happen :D Sure, it made an appearance, but backstory...? And it being pivotal? Not really.

Comment: @Moo perhaps season three, as Mandalore is about to come into focus and Din continues to be a reluctant hero...

Comment: @DarthLocke it feels like Disney is falling into the same old issue with SW that other things have in the past - far too much weight is put on you as a watcher knowing about something before its used in a mainstream show - I had zero investment in Mandalorian season 2 because I didnt care about any of the major characters introduced, yet they all seem to be “big” SW characters that I should have known about already.  It felt like I should be invested in them the moment we first saw them, and I wasnt because they were nothing to me.

Comment: @Moo I felt the opposite. While I like that Mando can have his smaller intimate adventures, from the start (given that this was always about Grogu's DNA), I felt like there was great opportunity to fill in sequel trilogy back story and begin to fulfill missing story and arcs from fantastic characters like Bo-Katan or Ahsoka (Ezra, Thrawn, etc). I have wanted to see these characters in live action for so long --it's nice to finally see it and perhaps get some of these stories that have been started elsewhere, resolved.

Comment: @DarthLocke your comment kinda makes my point for me - I had no investment in knowing who Bo-Katan or Ahsoka was, but they were introduced in a "woah, finally, these characters!" way in the second season.  I still have no investment in either character, and yet I'm supposed to be wowed by them and wanting more.

Answer (score -1):

The Darksaber was a lightsaber created by Tarre Vizsla, a Mandalorian *Jedi*. therefore the Jedi had jurisdiction over it. Plus, it was considered by the Jedi to be an artifact of their past. The Darksaber was both a lightsaber and one created by a Jedi, so the Jedi had claim over it. We can assume it was probably used in history lessons too, since it was a relic of the Jedi's history.

Also no, the kyber crystal of the darksaber is not aligned with the dark side. No kyber crystal is naturally aligned with the dark side. Dark sider users must 'bleed' their crystals to create the red colour. So yeah, it was probably neutral.

Comment: Got references?

Comment: I should of rephrased, I mean't could possibly be used in conjunction with dark side magic, because I feel like in the one rebels episode, one reason that Maul brought it helped the spirits of the night sisters claim living vessels in the rebels characters...and Resurrection or life extension tends to be the MO of the Sith/dark siders tend to seek...

Comment: Also the crystal may have come from the mines of Mandalore...I have a feeling Mando S3 may come to address this possibility.